# Android modal dialog stacking

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

My goal is to have a modal dialog display when the user navigates back to my app. This modal dialog asks them for a 6 digit PIN that they defined. I'm new to Java GUI and Android development so my problem is.....

I find that if the user chooses to minimize the app while the enterpin dialog is showing, if they return to the app the dialogs stack on top of each other. Making them enter their PIN as many times as they minimized and returned to the app during PIN entry.

```
/**
 * On restart called when the app is being restarted on the screen
 */
@Override
public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();



    // must prompt with modal dialog for pin

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    // check pin
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    // set view to enterpin XML screen
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.enterpin);


    // show dialog
    if (!dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.show();
    }
    // listen for button being clicked
    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pinlogin);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {// anonymous inner
        // class
        // implementation
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.enterpintext);
            try {
                int enteredPin = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText()
                        .toString());
                SharedPreferences sharedP = Prefs.get(WebViewActivity.this);
                int temp = sharedP.getInt("pin", 0);
                if (enteredPin == temp) {
                    pinCheck = true;



                    dialog.dismiss();
                } else {
                    pinCheck = false;
                    dialog.setTitle("Incorrect Pin");
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(WebViewActivity.this);
                dialog2.setTitle("Enter Numbers Only");
                dialog2.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                dialog2.show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Is there somewhere I could move my Dialog initialization without feeling like it's bad programming practice? I understand why the dialog.isShowing() method that I tried doesn't work because my Dialog instance only exists for the life of the method.

I also notice that should you turn the phone 90 degrees from vertical to horizontal orientation, and the otherway around, my dialogs disappear. Could someone point out the chain of methods called when this forced redraw happens so I can redraw my dialogs?

Comment: Your code solved my problem: the call to setCanceledOnTouchOutside.  However, I subclassed an Activity instead of a Dialog; in that case, the call is setFinishOnTouchOutside.  That, used in conjunction with android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" makes an activity behaive like a dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `onResume();` + `onPause();` and not `onRestart();` to create your dialog. You should use `onRestart();` to set a flag for the PIN dialog to be shown but not to create the dialog.

I'd suggest you move it to the `onCreate();` method, make it a property of the activity you're working on and simply display it in the `onResume();` method (since it will always be called every time the activity is active, even the first time).

Also, when the orientation changes, you need to list that you want to listen to the orientation changes event (via `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the activity manifest) and the `onConfigurationChanged();` method will be called on the active activity with the corresponding data. You can then redraw your dialogs to the new orientation.

Answer (score 1):

I get around the same problem (pin entry or otherwise) by storing by dialog in a property of the activity, whenever I show a dialog I use something along these lines:

```
protected android.app.Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        if (this.currentDialog != null) {
            this.currentDialog.dismiss();
        }

        this.currentDialog = null;

        switch (id) {
            case DIALOG_SPINNER:
                ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_Spinner_UpdatingAccount));
                progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

                this.currentDialog = progressDialog;
                break;
        }

        return this.currentDialog;

    }
```

I also dispose of the current dialog when the activity leaves the top of the stack (navigate or exited).

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (this.currentDialog != null) {
            this.currentDialog.dismiss();
        }

        super.onPause();
    }
```

The onPause method allows you to dismiss any dialog that is already open when you pause the activity, that way your existing onRestart code would just show a new dialog.